# How to find one number in table between two number in another table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables - one table for my rewards and another table for product I want get reward to personnel table such as below:

[image: product percentage]

[image: reward table]

I want know for example 78.12  in product line 2 how mach reward get for this must be know 78.12 between 40 and 87 and reward must be between 0 and 1

Comment: The field idline in table 1 is relate to the field lineid in table2?

Comment: yes idline and lineid is join key

Comment: So you example is input score=78.12 percentage = 40 and 87, output 0 and 1?

Comment: yes but percentage different for each product line

Comment: So you means 78.12 is between 40 and 87，so you want to find the region (0,1). You input is only score= 78.12 and idline = 2

Comment: Please [edit] your post to be more clear about what you're asking. We shouldn't have to play 20 questions in order to get the details. You should also include your efforts to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sql
select a.score,a.idline,
(select max(b.reward) from table2 b where a.idline = b.lineid and a.score > b.percentage) as  low,
(select min(b.reward) from table2 b where a.idline = b.lineid and a.score < b.percentage) as high
from table1 a
```

Comment: Rewrite a SQL based on the new understanding